# Magento 2 Rest api: unable to place order. getting error

Tags: magento, magento2

Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `PUT http://magento.localhost.com/rest/V1/carts/4/order` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"message":"Please specify a shipping method."}

My codes:

```
$shipBill = '{
 "addressInformation": {
  "shipping_address": {
   "id": 60,
   "customer_id": 1,
   "region": "Arkansas",
   "region_id": 5,
   "country_id": "US",
   "street": [
    "Whitefield,New York"
   ],
   "company": "IBM",
   "telephone": "94354545",
   "postcode": "234533",
   "city": "New York",
   "firstname": "test",
   "lastname": "test",
   "prefix": "address_",
   "region_code": "AR"
  },
  "billing_address": {
   "id": 60,
   "customer_id": 1,
   "region": "Arkansas",
   "region_id": 5,
   "country_id": "US",
   "street": ["Whitefield,New York"],
   "company": "IBM",
   "telephone": "94354545",
   "postcode": "234533",
   "city": "New York",
   "firstname": "test",
   "lastname": "test",
   "prefix": "address_",
   "region_code": "AR"
  },
  "shipping_method_code": "flatrate",
  "shipping_carrier_code": "flatrate"
     }
      }';
$checkout = $magento->createShippingAndBilling($quoteId, $shipBill)->getInArray();

$payment = '
    {
    "paymentMethod": {
        "method": "checkmo"
    }
}';
$order = $magento->orderCreate($quoteId, $payment)->getInArray();
```

I have added items on a cart by the rest API. Everything is working only when I tried to place an order I am getting this error.

Comment: I solved it myself. Thank you :)

Comment: please share what was the issue, other people with a similar issue can find it helpful

Comment: Missed a step. @DmitriPortenko
This code is working fine.